# Wordpress does not know the parametrs i sent to admin post

Tags: theme-development

I need to handle a post request with `admin-post`. This is the code of my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cat_filter">
    <select id="regionSelect" name="region" >
        <option value="none">choose region </option>
        <option value="option2">option two</option>
        <option value="option3">option three </option>
    </select>
    <select id="streetSelect" name="street">
        <option value="none">choose street </option>
        <option value="option2">option two</option>
        <option value="option3">option three </option>
    </select>   
    <button type="submit" class="button success small-12"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

In my `functions.php` file, i added this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_cat_filter', 'cat_filter_posts' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_cat_filter', 'cat_filter_posts' );
```

In the top of the functions file, i included another `PHP` file and in that file i write the function to do my job. The very first lines of this file are:

```
function cat_filter_posts() {
    if ($_POST['kind'] !="none") {
        $posts=new WP_Query(array( 'type'=> 'post', 'category_name'=> $_POST['kind']));
    }
}
```

But it's giving me an error for not recognizing the form values :

```
Notice: Undefined index: kind in /home2/address-to-file/examplefile.php
```

I think i just made every step correctly but this code is not working!

Comment: What is `$_POST['kind']`? Your fields are named `region` and `street`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an expected error because I cannot find any input field with `kind` name. There's only `action`, `region` and `street` no sign of `kind`!

> Notice: Undefined index: kind in
>   /home2/khiyabou/domains/khiyaboun.ir/public_html/wp-content/themes/khiyaboun-1/examplefile.php

So the above error is a perfect error in this situation. Please rewrite your callback function like the following. Hope that'll work

```
// It'll work for only street
function cat_filter_posts() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['street'] ) && 'none' != $_POST['street'] ) {
        $posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'type' => 'post',
            'category_name' => $_POST['street']
        ) );
    }
}
```